# Reload UITableView in edit mode

Tags: uitableview, reloaddata, editmode

I have a dictionary that holds every item in a list. I then have a plist that holds user information for each item in the list, including if the item has been collected or not. Then I load a UITableView with information based on the plist against the dictionary, only displaying items that the user still has not collected.

Users can tap on each row and navigate to a UIView page with information for the item with a static button to add the item to the completed list. When the button is pressed the program changes the "Completed" field related to the item in the users plist file to "YES" and when the user navigates back to the UITableView the item is removed from the list by calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the `viewDidAppear` function.

I also want the user to be able to enter "Edit mode" in the UITableView and select multiple rows to be added in one go. I have managed to get the functions working correctly, using `self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;` and `NSArray *temp = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows;` but the tableView will not refresh the screen until the user navigates out of the page and back in again. I have tried adding the `[self.tableView reloadData]` in different functions but none of them work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a reason why reloadData should not work, but IMO you should try

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation: (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

instead of `reloadData`(if you haven't already).
Also http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9 this could be of help.
Let me know if this works for you.